# Setting DNS for GitHub pages to avoid mail server conflict

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record, github

I would like to set up a github user page. I have created the repo and now I need to update my DNS records. I have the following DNS entries at the moment:

```
MX Records
mail.example.com

A Records
        123.45.67.89 (assume this is the default a record)
mail    123.45.67.89
www     123.45.67.89

CNAME
None
```

I would like my github page to be displayed at example.com. Do I update the www and default A records to the github IP and leave the mail pointing to the existing IP?

How do I redirect users that go to www.example.com to example.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can leave the `mail` IP as it is. You can delete the www record and set it as a CNAME to `example.com`. Then you change the "default" record to the GitHub IP as explained in the [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages). GitHub will handle the redirect.

Comment: The help page you linked suggests setting the `www` record as a CNAME of `username.github.io`.  There are good reasons for this.  Mostly it gives GitHub control over the actual IP address in use without having to contact everyone with a custom domain and wait for them to change their A records.

Comment: Sure it is reasonable but it depends if you want to use example.com or www.example.com. And that is a matter of tast. But I aggree. Using www as CNAME makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Their [documentation on this](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) doesn't mention mail.

All you need to do is set the `mail` A-record to be where you need it to go. It won't hurt the rest.

According to their documentation, www => bare-domain redirects are not built in. To get this you'll have to handle the redirects in the page-content itself, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your github page domain is `user.github.com` , then set CNAME to `user.github.com` for www.example.com and point example.com to Ip address of github.com

Dont disturb your mail A record. If you want to redirect users that go to `www.example.com` to `example.com` then check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011521/redirect-www-example-com-to-example-com

Comment: You can't set `example.com` to be a CNAME, only subdomains can be CNAMEs.  The domain root can only be an A record.  There's a warning about this on [Github's custom domain help page](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages).  Also, the CNAME should point to `user.github.io`.

Comment: @Ladadadada Sorry. example.com should be a A record . subdomains like `www.example.com` should have CNAME to `user.github.com`. thats how my blog is setup. I checked your help link and now github says to add CNAME to `user.github.io` So it is better to go with it. Edited my answer. thanks :)